# How are not all objects in category sets?

Tags: category-theory

Recently I saw a video talking about the Yoneda lemma from category theory being used in neuroscience. It was my first introduction to category theory. In category theory we have objects and maps between the same objects called morphisms. For example we have one type of object called set and its morphism would be the function. A function is a map from one set to another. Another example would be the object vector field with its morphisms being linear transformations. This just looks like we are renaming the same stuff.

Is a vector space not just a type of set we construct to obey our desired axioms? If so then introducing linear transforms would be truly just renaming stuff. And if they are not sets, why not allow non linear transforms?

Comment: Most "natural" categories of objects we study are where the objects are sets (endowed with extra structure). However, there are plenty of categories where objects have no internal structure at all. For example, if $G$ is a graph (a set of vertices and edges between vertices) then we can form $G$ into a category by making the vertices the objects and the edges the arrows. These graph categories are actually very important in category theory but the objects do not consist of sets and the arrows do not consist of set functions.

Comment: Not every set is a vector space, not every linear transformation is a function. In the category of sets, the objects are **al the sets**, and the arrows are **all the functions between the two sets**. In the category of vector spaces, the objects are "just" all the vector spaces, and the arrows are "just" all the linear transformations between the two vector spaces. There are categories where this doesn't happen. If $P$ is partially ordered, its elements can be objects and put an arrow between $x$ and $y$ if and only if $x\leq y$. That's a category.

Comment: A vector space is a set with structure. Let's say it is a vector space over a field $k.$ So $V$ with two functions $+:V\times V\to V, \cdot:k\times V\to V.$ You can represent this as a tuple, $(V,P,S)$ where $P\subset k\times V\times V$ and $S\subseteq V\times V\times V$ and, of course, tuples can be represented as a set, $\mathcal V,$ but the maps from one vector space to another is not a function on the tuples, but a function on the first element of the tuple.

Comment: The purpose of "renaming stuff" is abstraction. The logical structure of categories occurs in many areas of math, and the results of category theory apply to all of them (just like how linear algebra applies to anything that's a vector space).

Comment: That said, most of the categories you encounter at first have representations as sets with maps being some subset of the functions between those sets. An interesting simple example where it is hard to do so is the "opposite" category of a category.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "renaming stuff".

Comment: Another category you can choose where maps are not underlying functions is the category of relationships, where the objects are sets, but the maps from $A$ to $B$ are relationships between the sets, that is subsets of $A\times B.$

Comment: A relation can be thought of as functions $f:A\to \mathcal P(B),$ but these are two different sets. I guess you can think of relations as a subset of all functions $r:\mathcal P(A)\to \mathcal P(B),$ with the function having the property that $r(A_0)=\bigcup_{a\in A_0} r(\{a\})$ for any $A_0\subseteq A.$ But that is a surprising underlying set, given the definition.

Comment: In any event, viewing relations as functions obscures the symmetry of relations. If $r\subseteq A\times B,$ then there is a related $r^{op}\subseteq B\times A,$ and $(r\circ s)^{op}=s^{op}\circ r^{op}.$ But the functional definition does not make that clear at all,

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Not every linear transformation is a function?

Comment: @KritikerderElche Oops, "not every function is a libear transformation".